# Test-set error in cross-validation with regularization

Tags: cross-validation, regularization

I am performing regularization (Ridge regression) using cross validation. I understand that for a certain value of the regularization parameter $\lambda$, we first fit on the training-set and then we use the resulting parameters to calculate the error on the test-set and the optimal $\lambda$ is the one that minimizes the test-set error.
My question is: for the calculation of the test-set error do we include the penalty term (for the value of $\lambda$ that we used in the training set), or not (i.e. use $\lambda =0$)?
On one hand, I see the need to treat the training and test sets "on an equal footing" and use the same $\lambda$ for the test-set error calculation.
On the other hand, the parameter values that we get from fitting the training-set have already been *penalized*, and we want to see how these values perform on the test-set, so why use a penalty term again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the same value of λ on both training and test data sets.

The value of λ influences the values of the parameters. The values of the parameters should be consistent across training and test data sets, thus the value of λ should be the same.

Comment: Thanks Brian. I would agree that consistency is a good enough reason.